# How to access the Messenger platform app dashboard?

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, chatbot, facebook-messenger

As per the instructions, given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart), the tools for creating an app on the Messenger platform are under the Messenger tab in the old dashboard. But clicking on it opens just a blank page.

I'm not sure what am I missing here. Has Facebook not yet allowed access to developers all over the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today. Now it works. 
Simply refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the webhook first.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. Created the webhook and it authorized, but still a blank messages tab :-/

Comment: Subscribe your webhook to all the topics